# Symfony 5 Customise Class table inheritance with Doctrine-2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im just learning Symfony 5 and creating a dummy project,
Initially Doctrine class table inheritance was not working properly, I had to create a new application and create a schema with doctrine and now its working, but I feel its a bit of an anti-pattern and there seems to be repetition.

Ideally I only want to use Doctrine to fetch and persist entities to and from the database and nothing else, Ideally I do not want doctrine creating or managing the schema, I do not want to be forced to create a schema according to what Doctrine expects.
Otherwise it might be better for me to code without Doctrine as I know SQL properly but I might not be as good at managing entities in the Application.

To test Class table inheritance with Doctrine 2, I have created three simple entities:
Cat, Lion and Tiger,
Lion and Tiger extend from Cat.

Code for the entities:

```
//App\Entity\Cat.php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
use App\Repository\CatRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CatRepository::class)
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "lion" = "Lion",
 *      "tiger" = "Tiger"
 * })
 */
abstract class Cat
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
protected $breed;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getBreed(): ?string
{
    return $this->breed;
}

public function setBreed(?string $breed): self
{
        $this->breed = $breed;

        return $this;
    }
}

//App\Entity\Lion.php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LionRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use App\Entity\Cat;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=LionRepository::class)
 */
class Lion extends Cat
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lionProp;

    public function getLionProp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lionProp;
    }

    public function setLionProp(?string $lionProp): self
    {
        $this->lionProp = $lionProp;

        return $this;
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TigerRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use App\Entity\Cat;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TigerRepository::class)
 */
class Tiger extends Cat
{
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $tigerProp;

    public function getTigerProp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tigerProp;
    }

    public function setTigerProp(?string $tigerProp): self
    {
        $this->tigerProp = $tigerProp;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I would like to create the database separately not necessarily database first, so I can manage and fine tune the database myself separately from PHP.

According to this example I would like to create a database with two tables for Lion and Tiger, each having all the fields, no need for Cat,
However I want to make the most of OOP Inheritance so in the application I would like to make the most of inheritance

I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Lion(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    breed VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    lionProp VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT lionPk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Tiger(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    breed VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    tigerProp VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tigerPk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Now the obvious question might be, why not just let Doctrine handle this?
Mostly because Doctrine creates the following schema (not exactly but something along the lines of what is below):

```
CAT
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
breed VARCHAR(100) NULL,
discr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

LION
id INT NOT NULL
lionProp VARCHAR(100) NULL

TIGER
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
tigerProp VARCHAR(100) NULL
```

If I dont pass the discriminator column then it creates the following table for cat which is more or less the same, type instead of discr and the other two tables stay the same:

```
CAT
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
breed VARCHAR(100) NULL,
discr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

I dont like this mainly for the following reasons:

1. There is an unnecessary Cat Table,
   I am being forced to create an abstract class and it is being added to the database,
2. The cat table has a discr/dtype column which has a ridiculous amount of repetition, there is no need to have the table name repeated in a column on each row unless its single table inheritance
3. Even the primary key gets repeated twice once in the base table and in the other table
4. Every query requires a join, this is not performant when there is no need to create a join

This does not seem to be clean or performant to me,
What I would like is actual Class table inheritence where each entity that is being used has its own table with all fields as I described above,
Even though the column names and field are repeated, that's fine, because that is repeated only once and there is no duplication of data

Most importantly I do not feel a discriminator column should be there when using class table inheritence,

How could I implement this in doctrine?

Alternatively if what doctrine is providing is better than what I would like, then I am open to listening and sticking with this

Comment: What is `$em` in your code and where you define it?

Comment: Sorry that was the old example, code snippet updated, its the entity manager, getDoctrine()->getManager() but either way the biggest problem is Doctrine modified my tables when I updated the schema, and it has only created an id field in each table

Comment: So although everything works, only the id field gets populated everything else always stays null, Since Doctrine updated the schema, there are no other columns except for id in all 3 entities

Comment: Sometimes we get into a seemingly infinite loop trying to trouble shoot these sorts of things.  I created a fresh 5.1 project, copy/pasted in your entities (and just your entities) and then ran "bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql" with an empty database.  I got the expected three create table statements with the expected columns.  You might consider doing the same and then seeing what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that, so I assume there is nothing wrong with the syntax, Only thing Is in the future I want to administrate my own databases and not create schemas through Doctrine, because I like creating views, stored procedures and prefer to manage database in SQL Itself, Ideally I would like to only use Doctrine to fetch and persist entities, nothing more, I guess I could even do it without doctrine, In this project I have created a schema separate

Comment: I was able to successfully persist your lion example so the syntax seems fine.  You don't have to use doctrine to generate your schema.  I often copy/paste the --dump-sql into a ddl file to use as a starting point.  You do need to match Doctrine's expectations as far as naming and indexes go.  It is also possible to generate entities from an existing database.  But only as a starting point.  It's easy to encounter schemas that Doctrine has no idea how to process.  And a bit off-topic but I find that console commands are better for this sort of trouble shooting.

Comment: "You do need to match Doctrine's expectations as far as naming and indexes go" As in? The only thing I like to do is explicitly set constraints on tables, Doctrine keeps changing it to what it wants to do, I only really want Doctrine to get and put entities, nothing more,  but I guess this might interfere with how doctrine does it, in that case I might consider not using Doctrine, or using it and just letting it handle the schema, thank you

Comment: Even I am able to successfully persist it, but for some reason Doctrine only adds the id, all other fields always stay null, and are never added, you didn't experience this right? When I tried to create a form for that entity, only the id field came up, nothing else, I guess I will start over

Comment: I tested it one last time in the same project, the issue is the only id works

Comment: I tested it in a fresh application, it worked, but this seems like a bit of an anti-pattern, Lion and Tiger should have full entities with no need for a join, this is not performant, I will update the question if need be, here there is one entity for Cat which has the discr column which repeats the primary key twice as well as an extra column in the base table for all su b classes, this is not good

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Consider opening a discussion for this question.  And maybe read through [Doctrine Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Comment: not sure how to open a discussion lol, not very good at this, but I will look it up and consider it no problem, I have read the doctrine inheritance documentation, mostly vague and not a lot of in-depth information there